# Filtering without duplicates in mysql

Tags: mysql, left-join, alias, server-side

I'm fetching data from four different tables.  This is how I did:

```
select value_split.id,
count(invoice_request.id) as counts,
GROUP_CONCAT(`category`.`category_name`) as `category_name`
from value_split
left join invoice_request
on invoice_request.id = value_split.id
and MONTH(invoice_request.from_date) = '05'
and YEAR(invoice_request.from_date) = '2016'
and invoice_request.status = '1'
left join `category_value` on value_split.id = category_value.id 
left join `category` on category_value.category_id = category.category_id
where MONTH(value_split.date) = '05'
and YEAR(value_split.date) = '2016'
group by value_split.id, value_split.date
limit  0, 2147483647
```

The expected answer is:

```
id|counts|category_name
1 |  1   | service, drop
2 |  2   | drop
3 |  1   | service
```

But, what I get is:

```
id|counts|category_name
1 |  5   | service, drop
2 |  4   | drop
3 |  5   | service
```

If I remove line 10 and 11, I get the correct answer. But, if I include them, I get the wrong one. But, I want to display that too. So, what should I do to get the correct output? What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
COUNT(DISTINCT invoice_request.id) AS counts,
```

Comment: I tried using it, but I got 1 in the second column for all the ids.

Comment: What count you need? Use right expression for `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I used it in both the places, ie in line 2 as well as in 3. But, I go the same result.